# Merging Multiple Repos Into One NX Monorepo

Tags: reactjs, nx-monorepo

I'm diving into NX and I'm pretty new to it. I have a bit of a puzzle I'm trying to solve.

I currently have three separate repositories:

Client: It's a React TypeScript app (using React 17).
Server: An Express TypeScript application.
Storybook: Self-explanatory, it's for UI component development - react ts v18).
Now, I want to bring them all together into a single NX monorepo. (After that in the server repo, I have a utils folder that I want to extract into its own package).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Created an NX workspace using npx create-nx-workspace@latest org.
Installed the necessary NX plugins with npm i @nx/react @nx/express.
Generated a React application using nx g @nx/react:application --name=my-app --directory=apps/webapps/my-app.
Created an Express app with nx g @nx/express:app express-server --directory=apps/backend.
After that, I copied the files from the different repositories, but when I tried to run nx build my-app, I encountered this error: "Failed to load '.../org/apps/webapps/my-app/webpack.config.js' config."
```

I'm a little bit confused about how to proceed. Can anyone help me figure out the right approach?

Additionally, I'm concerned about dependency clashes between the client repo and Storybook. How can I configure it so that the node_modules will be separated for each project instead of shared at the root level?

Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated!.